# Can a Relationship Attribute turn into a Primary Key?

Tags: database

I would like to ask a question about Database Management.

So for example, I have a Relationship called 'Attends' with a few Relationship Attributes.

So when I turn this relationship into an Expanded Entity Relation Diagram, can an Attribute of this Relation turn into a Primary Key when this turns into an Entity?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the attribute unique and never `NULL`?  If so, it is a candidate primary key (note, some databases may also add a length or type restriction on the column).  I prefer synthetic keys, but any candidate could be used as the primary key.

Comment: yes.  or create a specific attribute that acts as a PK.